# How convert my existing activities to fragment with the same functionality and layout?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I wrote an android app that show content of three database table on the listview. For that I wrote three activities. But because of tablet view I made decision to use fragment instead  of activity to show content of two first list view on beside each other. For that I make an activity for manage the fragments and added my custom actionbar to onCreate method  and  it has layout in layout-large folder same as follow:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/poemlist"
    android:name="com.example.emampoems.poemTypeFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="com.example.emampoems.Index"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

and put following as layout of manager fragment on layout folder:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.emampoems.Index" />
```

after that I change the two first activity to fragment. just with exchange "extends activity" to "extends fragment" and change onCreate as oCreate of fragment and put the same instruction on that except put the layout on override of following method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_index, container, false);
}
```

I think with that my fragments used the previous activities 's layouts. but when I run it I get following error:
Unable to start activity componentInfo..android.view.inflatEException: Binary XML file line #8:Error inflating class fragment.
I googled this error but none of the answer wasn't useful for me and I get this yet. Is there any idea  why? I got this minus befor this question please ignore them and if I asked my question in right way please remove its minus please.

Comment: Configuration qualifiers are one of the things you should look at. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers   A ProTip: read the entire developers guide before you create apps.

Comment: there is a doc at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new fragment, and add the functionality from the activity's life cycle to the fragment's life cycle.

For example: 
your activity's onCreate()'s code should be implemented in onCreateView() of the fragment, off course you'll have to change some stuff like inflatting the view and returning it instead of calling setContentView(R.layout.id).

Implement it also for onResume(), onStop(), onPause() etc..

Then you'll need to implement a FragmentActivity and create and attach this fragment to it( you can do it from the xml or from the code), you can find out [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Fragments_in_Android_-_A_Worked_Example) how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful. I have another question but I can't ask on usual way. The fragment is left/right is it any way to make it right/left?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean..can you post another question and send me link?

Comment: Sorry. I can't add new question because I got lots of minus and need remove minus first. My means that I need change position of fragment that first fragment load on right side and second one on left.

Comment: Just do it in the xml, treat is as any other view